# String to functional math equation

Tags: objective-c, parsing, string-concatenation

Trying to create a simple calculator for `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` functions.

I've created a segmented box to pass an operator and two text fields to collect the values.

```
If 

txtBox1.text = 5

and


txtBox2.text = 9

and 

Operator = +
```

In xcode, how to I take the string I've created from this (`5+9`) and run the mathematics and return to the `txtBoxAnswer.text`?

Here is what I have:

```
NSString *theMath;

- (IBAction)operatorSelected:(id)sender {
    NSArray *theOperatorInCode =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+",@"-",@"*",@"/", nil];
    theMath = theOperatorInCode[_theOperator.selectedSegmentIndex];
}

- (IBAction)pressTheEquals:(id)sender {
    int first = [self.theFirstNumber.text floatValue];
    int second = [self.theSecondNumber.text floatValue];
    **NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d,%@,%d",first,theMath,second];**
}
```

Trying to take NSString Answer and put that string into a math equation.

Comment: What u have tried? Have u search on internet?

Comment: Lots of searching the internet.

Comment: So what u get? What problem u face with Wasif Hossain's answer.

Comment: Wasif's answer has the operator hard coded.  i.e. if statements to check the operator.  If you see by mine - the segmented box has four options available.  By selecting one, the variable theMath has the operator changed.  Then that is concatenated with values pulled from txtbox1 and txtbox2.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, indeed!

```
NSString *string1 = txtBox1.text;
NSString *string2 = txtBox2.text;

int number1 = [string1 intValue];
int number2 = [string2 intValue];

if([Operator isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
    int result = number1 + number2;
    txtBoxResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
}
```